# Rolling four dice, what are the odds of having at least a pair of sixes?

Tags: probability

Let's say I roll four dice. I want to know the odds of having at least two 6. There can be more too.

I did: 6C1 * 6C1, which gave me 36. I assumed the total possible combinations was 1296. I don't know if it's good, I doubt it is...

How do I know what the odds are of throwing 4 dice and at least getting two 6?

Comment: Why $6C1 \times 6C1$? Can you explain?

Comment: "at least two 6's" means _not_ $0$ and _not_ $1$. My guess is that _exactly_ $0$ and _exactly_ $1$ is easy to calculate (see Bright Star answer).

Comment: Pl don't use the word **odds** when you actually mean **probability**. It is a quite unnecessary obfuscation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Count the odds of 6 showing up 0x and 1x time, then use complement rule.

$\to$  0x time: $\frac{5^4}{6^4}$

$\to$  1x time:  $\frac{{4 \choose 1 }5^3}{6^4}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

**"At least 2"** means you can get **2 sixes on 4 tries** OR **3 sixes on four tries**, OR **all four sixes on four tries**.

Can you calculate the probabilities of these individual events?

In the end, use the fundamental principle of counting, and give the answer as the sum of all these probabilites.